# Shell Hotkey to Add File Name to Command

Tags: command-line, shell

I have forgotten the hotkey to add a filename when using commands such as "cd".
For example: cd (hotkey). and each time you press the hotkey, you get the name of one of the files in the current dir after "cd" so you don't have to type it.

I Googled it but I didn't have good keywords I think. No relevant result found.

Thank You

Comment: cd -press tab. This works in Windows cmd. In linux - cd then tab wont iterate through the files but gives list of entire files.

Comment: Well, you can configure the shell on Linux to provide them one of many ways.